# javascript remove lines matching pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove lines matching pattern 'WAN ipv4-address' from textarea '#textarea'

```
$("#textarea").val().replace(/WAN ipv4-address/g, '')
```

So I think above will only remove 'WAN ipv4-address' pattern from lines (in fact it doesn't even do this one for me). How to remove lines based on matching pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the return of `.replace()`:

```
$("#textarea").val($("#textarea").val().replace(/WAN ipv4-address/g, ''));
```

`Strings` are immutable this will return a new `String` you must use the new `String`.

Answer (score 1):

If ou want to remove the whole line then add `.*` before and after.

```
$("#textarea").val().replace(/.*WAN ipv4-address.*/g, '')
```

If you want to assign it back.

```
$("#textarea").val($("#textarea").val().replace(/.*WAN ipv4-address.*/g, ''));
```